# qt c++ QChart->setGeometry does not work in MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qchart

I created an object with a QChart inside and a MainWindow with 2 QPushButton, when I try to display my QChart, it takes all window. If I want to resize QChart everything works but if I try to move it nothing work (with setGeometry or with setContentMargin).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "Mainwindow.h"
#include "MainChart.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w(1920, 1080);
    MainChart chart;

    chart.setGeometry(250,0,1670,1080); // >> KO

    w.setCentralWidget(chart.get_view());
//    w.centralWidget()->setMaximumSize(1670, 1080); >> OK
//    w.centralWidget()->setContentsMargins(250,0,0,0); >> KO

    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Other files, I think that won't be useful but if need:

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QAction>
#include <Qt>
#include <QKeySequence>
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>

#include "Mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(int _width, int _height, QMainWindow *parent)
: width(_width), height(_height), QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setStyleSheet("MainWindow {background-color: rgb(40,40,40);}");

    this->setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint );
    this->showFullScreen();
    this->setFixedSize(width, height);

    configure_new_button();
    configure_exit_button();
    configure_escape();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    free(exit_btn);
    free(new_btn);
    free(escape);
}

void MainWindow::configure_exit_button()
{
    exit_btn = new QPushButton(this);
    exit_btn->connect(exit_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(exit()));
    exit_btn->setGeometry(0, height - 100, 100, 100);
    exit_btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(150,150,150);}");

    QFont font = exit_btn->font();
    font.setPointSize(32);
    exit_btn->setFont(font);

    exit_btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/close.png"));
    exit_btn->setIconSize(QSize(65, 65));

    exit_btn->show();
}

void MainWindow::configure_new_button()
{
    new_btn = new QPushButton(this);
    new_btn->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100);
    new_btn->connect(new_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(new_entry()));
    new_btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0,0,200);" "color: black");

    QFont font = new_btn->font();
    font.setPointSize(32);
    new_btn->setFont(font);

    new_btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/nouveau.png"));
    new_btn->setIconSize(QSize(65, 65));

    new_btn->show();
}

void MainWindow::configure_escape()
{
    escape = new QAction( "text4ESC", this );
    escape->setShortcut( Qt::Key_Escape );
    escape->setShortcutContext( Qt::WindowShortcut );
    connect(escape, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(exit()));
    addAction(escape);
}

void MainWindow::exit()
{
    close();
    qApp->quit();
}

void MainWindow::new_entry()
{
    std::cout << "coucou !!!" << std::endl;
}
```

**Mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MainWindow(int _width, int _height, QMainWindow *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        void configure_exit_button();
        void configure_new_button();
        void configure_escape();

    private slots:
        void exit();
        void new_entry();

    private:
        QPushButton *exit_btn;
        QPushButton *new_btn;
        QAction *escape;
        int width;
        int height;
};

#endif //MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Mainchart.cpp**

```
#include "MainChart.h"

MainChart::MainChart(QChart *Parent)
{
    QBarSet *set0 = new QBarSet("Altuve");
    QBarSet *set1 = new QBarSet("Martine");
    QBarSet *set2 = new QBarSet("Bob");

    *set0 << 256 << 954 << 752 << 148 << 596 << 214;
    *set1 << 586 << 369 << 485 << 874 << 693 << 587;
    *set2 << 785 << 963 << 547 << 745 << 657 << 874;

    QFont font;
    font.setPixelSize(18);

    QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries();
    series->append(set0);
    series->append(set1);
    series->append(set2);

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->setTitle("Mon Super Graphique");
    chart->setTitleFont(font);
    chart->setTitleBrush(QBrush(qRgb(255,255,255)));
    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);

    QStringList categories;
    categories << "2013" << "2014" << "2015" << "2016" << "2017";

    QBarCategoryAxis *axis = new QBarCategoryAxis();
    axis->append(categories);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setAxisX(axis, series);

    font.setPixelSize(12);
    chart->axisX()->setLabelsBrush(QBrush(qRgb(255,255,255)));
    chart->axisX()->setLabelsFont(font);
    chart->axisY()->setLabelsBrush(QBrush(qRgb(255,255,255)));
    chart->axisY()->setLabelsFont(font);

    chart->legend()->setVisible(true);
    chart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);
    chart->legend()->setLabelColor(qRgb(255,255,255));
    chart->legend()->setFont(font);

    chart->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QRgb(0x0)));

    chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
}
MainChart::~MainChart() {}

QChartView * MainChart::get_view()
{
    return chartView;
}
```

**Mainchart.h**

```
#ifndef NEW_MAINCHART_H
#define NEW_MAINCHART_H

#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QSplineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QBarSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QBarSet>
#include <QtCharts/QBarCategoryAxis>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class MainChart : public QChart
{
    public:
        MainChart(QChart *Parent = 0);
        ~MainChart();
        QChartView *get_view();

    private:
        QChartView *chartView;
};


#endif //NEW_MAINCHART_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to look at using layouts. I'm not entirely positive, but making the chart the window's central widget means it's going to take up all the space -- just the way it's behaving.

It sounds like what you should do is create a widget and consider it a container. It becomes your central widget, and then you add things to it. But without a layout, you're going to get weird resize behavior.

It's really far better to grow accustomed to handling layouts using a layout rather than hard-coded size & locations. You have to use widgets as containers to make things work, but everything I've tried to do I've been able to do.